# Regex should not substitute character before matching string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex problem:

```
import re
a1 = '<href="§ 5"> asd'
a2 = 'asdas § 5 asdas '

a1 = re.sub(r'[^"](§ \d+)', r"§\1", a1)
a2 = re.sub(r'[^"](§ \d+)', r"§\1", a2)
```

For string `a1` nothing be should be substituted, as `"` is before the § with the number. That works fine. For the second string `a2`, the § the substitution should take place and is supposed to result in `asdas §§ 5 asdas`. But the regex function also substitutes the space before, resulting in `asdas§§ 5 asdas`. How can I change the regex that it doesn't include the space before the §.

Comment: capture non-quote character and back-reference it: `a2 = re.sub(r'([^"])(§ \d+)', r"\1§\2", a2)`

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind instead of a negated character class.

Comment: Note that your regexp also won't work if `§ 5` is at the beginning of the line, because `[^"]` won't match before that. A negative lookbehind solves that problem as well.

Comment: @anubhava, changing your regex to `r'([^"])?(§ \d+)', r"\1§\2"` (adding the question mark) causes `'§ 5 asdas '` to be converted to `'§§ 5 asdas '`, as may be desired (possibly requiring the Python version to be sufficiently new).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to use no capture groups at all, by replacing a zero-width match of the following regular expression with `'§'`:

```
rgx = r'(?<!")(?=§ \d)'
```

```
re.sub(rgx, '§', '<href="§ 5"> asd')    #=> '<href="§ 5"> asd'
re.sub(rgx, '§', 'asdas § 5 asdas ')    #=> 'asdas §§ 5 asdas '
re.sub(rgx, '§', '§ 5 the cat came in') #=> '§§ 5 the cat came in'
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurKL1CwVahSF3D3kZRSVPD3vbQcoWYFE11Lq6Cosy8Eo2iVL3i0iQNoDIdBfVDy9WBpE1GUWqarRJQoamSnUJicYq6piZu1UD5xGIFkGIFCBOvarC6koxUheTEEiDOTVXIzANp@P8fAA)

`(?<!")` is a *negative lookbehind* which asserts that the current string location is not preceded by a double-quote. `(?=§ \d)` is a *positive lookahead* which asserts that the current string location is followed by `'§ '` followed by a digit. When both lookarounds are satisfied a match is made of the zero-width location immediately before `'§'` and `re.sub` directs that that location is to be replaced with the string `'§'`.

Notice that `(?=§ \d+)` is satisfied if `(?=§ \d)` is satisfied, so matching a digit after the space is sufficient.

I also like the way this reads: "insert `'§'` before `'§'` when the latter is followed by a space and then a digit, and is not preceded by a double-quote".

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'(^|[^"])(§\s*\d+)', r'\1§\2', a1)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/7XZbjB/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]                     any character except: '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    §                        '§'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```